# TensorFlow-GPU errors after installation(Windows 10)

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am getting a ton of errors trying to test if TF is installed or not.
typing this in anaconda prompt.
I am currently using Python 3.6.12, TensorFlow 1.13.1 and I am on Windows 10.

```
python
import tensorflow as tf
```

and then I get these Errors:

```
>>> import tensorflow as tf
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\PC\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow1\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Users\PC\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow1\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Users\PC\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow1\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "C:\Users\PC\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow1\lib\imp.py", line 243, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "C:\Users\PC\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow1\lib\imp.py", line 343, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\PC\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow1\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow  # pylint: disable=unused-import
  File "C:\Users\PC\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow1\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "C:\Users\PC\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow1\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 74, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\PC\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow1\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Users\PC\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow1\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Users\PC\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow1\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "C:\Users\PC\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow1\lib\imp.py", line 243, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "C:\Users\PC\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow1\lib\imp.py", line 343, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.
```

This is after I used conda create --name tftest python=3.6 tensorflow-gpu=1.13.1

```
>>> import tensorflow as tf
C:\Users\PC\anaconda3\envs\tftest\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\dtypes.py:526: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_qint8 = np.dtype([("qint8", np.int8, 1)])
C:\Users\PC\anaconda3\envs\tftest\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\dtypes.py:527: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_quint8 = np.dtype([("quint8", np.uint8, 1)])
C:\Users\PC\anaconda3\envs\tftest\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\dtypes.py:528: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_qint16 = np.dtype([("qint16", np.int16, 1)])
C:\Users\PC\anaconda3\envs\tftest\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\dtypes.py:529: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_quint16 = np.dtype([("quint16", np.uint16, 1)])
C:\Users\PC\anaconda3\envs\tftest\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\dtypes.py:530: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_qint32 = np.dtype([("qint32", np.int32, 1)])
C:\Users\PC\anaconda3\envs\tftest\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\dtypes.py:535: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  np_resource = np.dtype([("resource", np.ubyte, 1)])
>>> hello=tf.constant('hey')
>>> sess=tf.Session()
2020-10-11 20:11:50.345953: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:141] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX AVX2
2020-10-11 20:11:50.863978: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1433] Found device 0 with properties:
name: GeForce 940MX major: 5 minor: 0 memoryClockRate(GHz): 0.993
pciBusID: 0000:01:00.0
totalMemory: 1.00GiB freeMemory: 820.30MiB
2020-10-11 20:11:50.870374: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1512] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
```

Comment: How did you install `tensorflow`? I suggest you install a fresh tensorflow in a complete new conda environment like `conda create --name tfgpu21_py37 python=3.7 tensorflow-gpu` where `tfgpu21_py37` is the environment name. I have rarely seen this failing, provided you execute it correctly.

Comment: @AtherCheema Thank you very much I just tried it I think I just got a fey  warnings.

Comment: Problem seems to have been solved after you used `conda` for installation; apart from the first warning (which is not actually an issue), the other are just informational ones and do not signify any error or issue. The question seems irrelevant now, so please either clarify if you are still facing issues, or kindly delete it.